# InputScope for TextBox not working anymore?

Tags: textbox, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, inputscope

In my WinRT/C# app I have a XAML file with various input boxes (`TextBox`). Each textbox has an `InputScope` property defined, thus the on-screen keyboard should display individually (e.g. for `InputScope="Number"`).

In the Win8 Release Preview the `InputScope` yielded the correct result and showed different keyboard layouts. Now I've switched to the Win8 RTM and this seems not to work anymore. Regardless to the `InputScope` property value, the on-screen keyboard layout is everytime the same (default) layout.

Somebody who can reproduce this or can give me a hint how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the following test...

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number"/>
```

and it worked correctly.  Also tried it with several other inputscopes and they all worked correctly as well.

Comment: Strange... I will check it again... perhaps a reboot will help ;-)

Comment: I fear I was right with my "reboot" theory. After restarting my PC, everything works fine again. Thanks...